# How to show content from contentPlaceholder inline

Tags: asp.net, placeholder

I have a page where in my masterpage have a toolbar with a "Home" button to the far left. This button is not in a `contentplaceholder` but on the page.

I want to have the opportunity for derived pages to add their own controls or whatever to the toolbar to be whown *after* the "home" button. But how to do this?

I have tried to put in a `contentplaceholder`, but it seems that I cannot get it to show inline with the other stuff, it breaks and the content of the `contentplaceholder` is shown below the button instead.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**Update:**

Regarding the comment from @Remy below:

> Do you, by chance, have a line break
>   in the masterpage's markup between the
>   button and contentplaceholder?

I started looking and because I'm a bit inexperienced at designing with CSS (when aligning text and an image vertically center). I created a table that enclosed each button - forgot that table are block elements, so there was my line break.

Comment: Do you mean merge the markup in both the master's content place holder place holder and the form's? If so this is not possible.

Comment: No, not merge, the "home" toolbar button is _not_ in a content placeholder, its in the masterpage markup. I "just" want to show a content placeholder "inline" behind my toolbar button, now it makes a linebreak and is shown as "block"

Comment: Do you, by chance, have a line break in the masterpage's markup between the button and contentplaceholder?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

- from derived page you can get to the master page content over `Page.MasterPage`, and manipulate by controls located there. So you just need to allocate at master server-div or Panel and locate it by `Page.MasterPage.FindControl` to populate with particular inline elements
- ContentPlaceholder does nothing with HTML layout, so you header can looks like:

  ```
  <div>
      <span> <!-- your Home button declaration goes there --> </span> 
      <span> <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ... </span>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the toolbar in the MasterPage available through a public property. Then you can access the master page from the content using `Content.Master` propery.  Then you can add the controls to the toolbar as you add any runtime control.

Also, you need to Typecase the `Content.Master` to the type of your master file class before accessing its public property.

Comment: What i forgot to mention is that this is MVC, so i dont have access to the master (at least not that i know of)